# Flutter Provider - Call function on value change without calling build()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am wondering if it is possible to watch for a value change inside an initState which then simply calls a function?

I basically need to start and stop a timer given the status of a class i am observing with Provider (listen: true)  and was hoping there was some callback functionality that i could trigger instead of build() being called each time?

For example something like..

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Provider.of<MyService>(context, listen: true).serviceRunning => { 
     //do stuff (start/stop my local timer)
     if(serviceRunning) {
       serviceRunning()
     } else {
       serviceStopped()
     }
  }
}

void serviceRunning() {
  //start local timer and other bits
}

void serviceStopped() {
  //stop local timer and other bits
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ..
}
```

I don't recall Provider being able to do this, so would appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve this.  As mentioned above, i am just trying to save having build() get called unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Not a provider user here (bloc fan) but you should be able to do what you want with a ValueNotifier exposed by your service. And in your initState you would add a listener to the notifier.

And I believe you can avoid build call by using `context.select<T, R>(R cb(T value))`, which allows a widget to listen to only a small part of T.
Extract of the provider doc:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final name = context.select((Person p) => p.name);
  return Text(name);
}
```

But I'm not sure that this is necessary.

If you find a cleaner solution please share it, it's  always nice learning what works in other part of the flutter community.